# How to turn on/off DATA programmatically without modifying APN (Gingerbread compatible)?

Tags: android

I only found during my research solutions that either involve a modification of the APNs, or are not compatible with Android 2.3 because of its enhanced security.

Nevertheless, I am pretty sure there is a **faster/cleaner way** than modifying the APNs to enable/disable mobile data connectivity. Indeed, one of the most popular widgets on the market manages to do the switch very quickly and claims it does not touch APNs.

-> Do you know which API/function I should use to get similar functionality in my app ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible due to security reasons.  The only alternative is to modify the APN, and it is not guaranteed to work in every device.

Comment: `Data Enabler Widget` on the market manages to turn off data really quick, so there must be a workaround for this security limitation (other than switching to a fake APN).